# npm install ethereum/web3.js - gives me an error

Tags: npm-install, ethereum, go-ethereum

npm install ethereum/web3.js --save

I get:
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue but it's simple to solve it. Follow the below step it works for me.

1) Download git from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and install on your PC.

2) Then just restart your CMD.

3) Then Execute `npm install ethereum/web3.js --save` Command.

And you are good to go. Hope it will be helpful for others also.

Answer (score 0):

- Run cmd with Administrator privilege
- Run => `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
- Run => `npm install --save web3@1.0.0-beta.26` (in your project directory)

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me! simply type web3.js